# rounded value in array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have array of objects and I want to round value to the nearest integer. Do you have idea how i can do?

`items.forEach(item => console.log(item.value.toFixed(0)));`

but I need number, not string.

I also tried with using map

`items.map(item => item.value.toFixed(0)).map(Number);`

but i don't want to change item to item.value

I hope you help me.

```
const items = [
    {
        name: 'pen',
        value: 10.12
    },
    {
        name: 'rubber',
        value: 5.99
    }
];
```

Comment: [Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

Comment: `forEach` approach is almost correct, Instead of `toFixed`. try `parseInt` or Math.round

Comment: Use `Math.round()`

Comment: Try this. items.forEach((item)=> Math.round(item.value));

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

```js
const items = [
    {
        name: 'pen',
        value: 10.12
    },
    {
        name: 'rubber',
        value: 5.99
    }
];

var results = items.map(item => Math.round(item.value));

console.log(results);
```

You can of course keep your original object if you wanted, for which using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) of `...items` preserves all of the properties of your existing object - just overwriting `value` as necessary with its rounded version.

```js
const items = [
    {
        name: 'pen',
        value: 10.12
    },
    {
        name: 'rubber',
        value: 5.99
    }
];

var results = items.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  value: Math.round(item.value)
}));

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Math.round()` will round the number to nearest integer

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new property to the objects in the array like so:

```js
    const items = [
        {
            name: 'pen',
            value: 10.12
        },
        {
            name: 'rubber',
            value: 5.99
        }
    ];

    items.forEach(item => item.rounded = Math.round(item.value));

    console.log(items);
```

This will give you:

```
  {
    "name": "pen",
    "value": 10.12,
    "rounded": 10
  },
  {
    "name": "rubber",
    "value": 5.99,
    "rounded": 6
  }
]
```

Comment: You may as well make this a `forEach` - you're ignoring the result of `map` and even if you weren't `results` would be an array of rounded values.

Comment: I agree there is no need for storing this in ```results```. Just do ```items.forEach(item => item.rounded = Math.round(item.value));```.